# Difference in Action initialization

Tags: java, swing, event-handling, action

I tried to create program, in which class of Action is an inner class of one class, but initialization of its objects occur in an another class, however I get an exception all the time. Below I present simplified model of my problem:

There is one class which build GUI and contains inner class of Action:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.InputEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class SomeClass {
    JTextArea area;
    public static void main(String[] args){
        SomeClass outerAction = new SomeClass();
        outerAction.go();
    }
    public void go(){
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    area = new JTextArea(5,10);
    JToolBar toolBar = new JToolBar(SwingConstants.HORIZONTAL);
    CreateAction createAction = new CreateAction();
    JButton button1 = new JButton(innerGetAction());
    JButton button2 = new JButton(createAction.otherGetAction());
    toolBar.add(button1);
    toolBar.add(button2);

    frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.PAGE_START,toolBar);
    frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER,area);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
public Action innerGetAction(){
    Action action = new SomeAction("DO","Do sth",KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_N, InputEvent.CTRL_MASK));
    return action;
}
    public class SomeAction extends AbstractAction{
        public SomeAction(String name, String desc, KeyStroke key){
            super(name);
            putValue(SHORT_DESCRIPTION,desc);
            putValue(ACCELERATOR_KEY,key);
        }
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            area.setText("Done");
        }
    }
}
```

There is a two JButtons with same Action, however initialozation of first occur in SomeClass, and an another in seperate CreateActionClass:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.InputEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class CreateAction {
    public static Action otherGetAction(){
        Action action = new SomeClass().new SomeAction("DO","Do sth",KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_N, InputEvent.CTRL_MASK));
        return action;
    }
}
```

One button works fine, another gives exception. I don't understand why.

Could you please tell me:

1. Why Action initialized in class CreateAction don't have an acces to field from SomeClass?
   If getAction is a method of SomeClass, everything is ok, it can modify JTextArea, but when it is a method of CreateAction, there is a java.lang.NullPointerException. What is a difference?
2. Is it make sense to initialize Action object in different class, than its Action class and a constructor is placed?

Forgive me my pathetic example.

Stacktrace:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at SomeClass$SomeAction.actionPerformed(SomeClass.java:40)
>       at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
>       at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2346)
>       at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
>       at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
>       at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
>       at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:289)
>       at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6525)
>       at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
>       at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6290)
>       at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
>       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4881)
>       at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
>       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
>       at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
>       at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4533)
>       at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
>       at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
>       at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2739)
>       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:746)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:719)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:717)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:716)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)

Comment: Please see edit to answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're getting a NullPointerException because you're using the wrong SomeClass to create the Action here:

```
Action action = new SomeClass().new SomeAction("DO", "Do sth",
        KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_N, InputEvent.CTRL_MASK));
```

This `new SomeClass()` is not the displayed SomeClass!

Instead consider passing in the visualized object.

```
public static Action otherGetAction(SomeClass someClass) {
  return someClass.new SomeAction("DO", "Do sth",
        KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_N, InputEvent.CTRL_MASK));
}
```

---

Consider separating the Action out of the GUI if you're going to be setting it outside of the GUI. For example:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Test2 extends JPanel implements Fooable {
   private JTextField field = new JTextField(10);
   private JTextArea textarea = new JTextArea(20, 30);
   private JButton button = new JButton();

   public Test2() {
      textarea.setFocusable(false);
      JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textarea);
      scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

      add(field);
      add(scrollPane);

      add(button);
   }

   public void setActions(Action action) {
      button.setAction(action);
      field.setAction(action);
   }

   @Override
   public String getFieldText() {
      field.selectAll();
      return field.getText();
   }

   @Override
   public void appendText(String text) {
      textarea.append(text + "\n");
   }


   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      Test2 mainPanel = new Test2();
      Action myAction = new MyAction("Press Me", KeyEvent.VK_P, mainPanel);
      mainPanel.setActions(myAction);

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test2");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }

}

interface Fooable {
   String getFieldText();
   void appendText(String text);
}

class MyAction extends AbstractAction {
   private Fooable fooable;

   public MyAction(String name, int mnemonic, Fooable fooable) {
      super(name);
      putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, mnemonic);
      this.fooable = fooable;
   }

   @Override
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      if (fooable != null) {
         fooable.appendText(fooable.getFieldText());
      }
   }
}
```